# Mouse keys on GNOME with no keypad

Tags: gnome3, mouse, accessibility

How do I use mouse keys (Universal Access -> Pointing & Clicking -> Mouse Keys) when I have no keypad?

My goal is to work mouse-free.

Comment: Is it possible to use some remapping of the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

map some keyboard shortcuts to execute following commands:

## up

xdotool mousemove_relative -- 0 -10

## down

xdotool mousemove_relative -- 0 10

## left

xdotool mousemove_relative -- -10 0

## right

xdotool mousemove_relative -- 10 0

see man xdotool for more details